# ¿Cómo sobrecargar el operador de inyección de datos para una clase interna de una clase plantilla?

Tags: c++, template, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Tengo una clase plantilla que contiene una clase interna a la cuál se puede acceder con un método:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class Externa
{
    struct Interna{};

public:
    Interna f() { return {}; };
};
```

Quiero sobrecargar el operador de inyección de datos a flujo de salida para la clase interna, para así poder hacer lo siguiente:

```
Externa<int, int> e;
std::cout << e.f();
```

He declarado la función amiga en la clase interna:

```
struct Interna
{
    template <typename A_, typename B_>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const typename Externa<A_, B_>::Interna &);
};
```

Y la he definido fuera:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const typename Externa<A, B>::Interna &i)
{
    return o << &i;
}
```

Pero no parece funcionar:

> ```
> error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'Externa<int, int>::Interna')
>         std::cout << e.f();
>         ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~
>              |          |
>              |          Externa<int, int>::Interna
>              std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
> ```

¿De qué manera debe declararse y definirse la sobrecarga del operador de inyección de datos a flujo de salida para una clase interna de una clase plantilla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declara e implementa la sobrecarga **dentro** de `Interna`:

```
struct Interna{
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream & o, const Interna & i)
  {
    return o << &i;
  }
};
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xghoCyZy7Vxe12iA)

No puedes implementar la función fuera porque el compilador no es capaz de deducir `A_` y `B_`. Aunque a nosotros nos parezca obvio que `Interna` viene de `Externa<A_, B_>` para el compilador no es algo tan obvio. Como no es capaz de encontrar una equivalencia válida te muestra el error y a otra cosa.

Comment: Al final la solución más obvia era la que estaba descartando.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster a mi eso me pasa muchas veces